# Printing all alignments of two sequences with maximum score

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

[Sequence Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) is quite a standard problem and finds application in DNA or protein alignment in the field of Bioinformatics. I recently came across a different version of this problem.

Given two input strings(assume that strings are made up of only A,C,G,T), the problem basically was to find the maximum alignment score based on the following matrix --

```
   A  C  G  T  -
A  5 -1 -2 -1 -3  
C -1  5 -3 -2 -4
G -2 -3  5 -2 -2
T -1 -2 -2  5 -1
- -3 -4 -2 -1 Not Allowed
```

So,if A is aligned with -, we add -3 to the alignment score or if G is aligned with T, we add -2 to the score or if C is aligned with C, we add 5.
So, for input strings AGTGATG and GTTAG, the maximum alignment score is 14 and one of the alignments with maximum score can be represented as

```
AGTGATG
-GTTA-G
```

The alignment score is calculated as follows : A- = -3, GG = 5, TT = 5, GT= -2, AA = 5, T-= -1 and GG = 5. Adding them up, -3+5+5-2+5-1+5 = 14 which is the maximum possible alignment score for this pair of strings.

I am able to code it up using dynamic programming and get the Alignment score matrix but I am facing problems in printing all possible alignments of the two strings with maximum alignment score. I tried to backtrack as we do in LCS but could not make it work. I am attaching my code.

```
static Dictionary<string, int> dict;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This has been assumed that the strings contain only A,C,G,T and -(?)..caps

        Console.WriteLine("Enter first string : ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        a = "-" + a;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second string : ");
        string b = Console.ReadLine();
        b = "-" + b;
        int[,] SQ = new int[a.Length, b.Length];
        #region Create Dictionary
        dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("AA", 5);
        dict.Add("AC", -1);
        dict.Add("AG", -2);
        dict.Add("AT", -1);
        dict.Add("A-", -3);

        dict.Add("CA", -1);
        dict.Add("CC", 5);
        dict.Add("CG", -3);
        dict.Add("CT", -2);
        dict.Add("C-", -4);

        dict.Add("GA", -2);
        dict.Add("GC", -3);
        dict.Add("GG", 5);
        dict.Add("GT", -2);
        dict.Add("G-", -2);

        dict.Add("TA", -1);
        dict.Add("TC", -2);
        dict.Add("TG", -2);
        dict.Add("TT", 5);
        dict.Add("T-", -1);

        dict.Add("-A", -3);
        dict.Add("-C", -4);
        dict.Add("-G", -2);
        dict.Add("-T", -1);
        dict.Add("--", 0);
        #endregion Create Dictionary

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
            {
                int key = 0, key1 = 0, key2 = 0;
                dict.TryGetValue(a[i].ToString() + b[j].ToString(), out key);
                dict.TryGetValue("-" + b[j].ToString(), out key1);
                dict.TryGetValue(a[i].ToString() + "-", out key2);
                if (i == 0)
                    SQ[i, j] = key1;
                else if (j == 0)
                    SQ[i, j] = key2;
                else
                    SQ[i, j] = Math.Max(SQ[i - 1, j - 1] + key, Math.Max(SQ[i - 1, j] + key1, SQ[i, j - 1] + key2));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(SQ[i, j] + "   ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Alignment Score : " + SQ[a.Length - 1, b.Length - 1]);            
        printAllAlignmentsWithHighestAlignmentScore();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Can somebody please help me in implementing printAllAlignmentsWithHighestAlignmentScore() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have the working code to do exactly what I wanted to do.
The problem is actually a slight variation of [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm)

Code :

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, int> dict;
    static void printAllAlignments(int[,] SQ, string a, string b, int p, int q, string str1, string str2){
        if (p == 0 || q == 0){
            while (p == 0 && q != 0){
                str1 = "-" + str1;
                str2 = b[--q]+str2;
            }
            while (q == 0 && p != 0){
                str1 = a[--p]+str1;
                str2 = '-' + str2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n"+str1+"\n"+str2+"\n");
            return;
        }

        if (SQ[p, q] == (dict[a[p - 1] + b[q - 1].ToString()] + SQ[p - 1, q - 1]))
            printAllAlignments(SQ, a, b, p - 1, q - 1, a[p-1]+str1, b[q-1]+str2);

        if (SQ[p, q] == (dict[a[p - 1]+ "-"] + SQ[p - 1, q]))
            printAllAlignments(SQ, a, b, p - 1, q, a[p-1]+str1, "-"+str2);

        if (SQ[p, q] == (dict["-" + b[q-1]] + SQ[p, q - 1]))            
            printAllAlignments(SQ, a, b, p, q - 1, "-"+str1, b[q-1]+str2);


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This has been assumed that the strings contain only A,C,G,T and -(?)..caps

        Console.WriteLine("Enter first string : ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();         
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second string : ");
        string b = Console.ReadLine();          
        int[,] SQ = new int[a.Length+1, b.Length+1];

        #region Create Dictionary
        dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("AA", 5);
        dict.Add("AC", -1);
        dict.Add("AG", -2);
        dict.Add("AT", -1);
        dict.Add("A-", -3);

        dict.Add("CA", -1);
        dict.Add("CC", 5);
        dict.Add("CG", -3);
        dict.Add("CT", -2);
        dict.Add("C-", -4);

        dict.Add("GA", -2);
        dict.Add("GC", -3);
        dict.Add("GG", 5);
        dict.Add("GT", -2);
        dict.Add("G-", -2);

        dict.Add("TA", -1);
        dict.Add("TC", -2);
        dict.Add("TG", -2);
        dict.Add("TT", 5);
        dict.Add("T-", -1);

        dict.Add("-A", -3);
        dict.Add("-C", -4);
        dict.Add("-G", -2);
        dict.Add("-T", -1);
        dict.Add("--", 0);
        #endregion Create Dictionary

        SQ[0, 0] = 0;            
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.Length; i++)            
            SQ[i, 0] = dict["-" + a[i - 1].ToString()] + SQ[i - 1, 0];

        for (int i = 1; i <= b.Length; i++)
            SQ[0, i] = dict[b[i - 1].ToString() + "-"] + SQ[0, i - 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= a.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.Length; j++)
                SQ[i, j] = Math.Max(SQ[i - 1, j - 1] + dict[a[i-1].ToString() + b[j-1]], Math.Max(SQ[i - 1, j] + dict[a[i-1] + "-"], SQ[i, j - 1] + dict["-" + b[j-1]]));           


        Console.WriteLine("Max Alignment Score : " + SQ[a.Length, b.Length]);
        printAllAlignments(SQ, a, b, a.Length , b.Length,"","");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Where is the "dynamic programming" in your code?

I'm not sure what you're looking for in printing all possible alignments but my quick and dirty code below may help. It prints each alignment over two lines, like this:

```
- 0
-

- -2
G

.
.
.

AGTGATG 8
-GTTTTA

AGTGATTG 14
-GTTTTAG
```

Note that the maximum alignment combination you mentioned doesn't show up in this output:

```
AGTGATG
-GTTA-G
```

Is this what you mean by "problems in printing all possible alignments"?

Anyway here's my code (dictionary initialization removed):

```
public struct Alignment
{
    public string substringA;
    public string substringB;
    public int key;
}

[MTAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //This has been assumed that the strings contain only A,C,G,T and -(?)..caps

    Console.WriteLine("Enter first string : ");
    var a = Console.ReadLine();
    a = "-" + a;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second string : ");
    var b = Console.ReadLine();
    b = "-" + b;
    Alignment[,] SQ = new Alignment[a.Length, b.Length];

    #region Create Dictionary
    ...
    #endregion Create Dictionary

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
        {
            int key = 0, key1 = 0, key2 = 0;
            dict.TryGetValue(a[i].ToString() + b[j].ToString(), out key);
            dict.TryGetValue("-" + b[j].ToString(), out key1);
            dict.TryGetValue(a[i].ToString() + "-", out key2);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                SQ[i, j].substringA = "-";
                SQ[i, j].substringB = b[j].ToString();
                SQ[i, j].key = key1;
            }
            else if (j == 0)
            {
                SQ[i, j].substringA = a[i].ToString();
                SQ[i, j].substringB = "-";
                SQ[i, j].key = key2;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the maximum key value, and the substrings associated with it.
                int score;
                var score1 = SQ[i - 1, j].key + key1;
                var score2 = SQ[i, j - 1].key + key2;
                if (score1 >= score2)
                {
                    SQ[i, j].substringA = SQ[i - 1, j].substringA;
                    SQ[i, j].substringB = SQ[i - 1, j].substringB;
                    score = score1;
                }
                else
                {
                    SQ[i, j].substringA = SQ[i, j - 1].substringA;
                    SQ[i, j].substringB = SQ[i, j - 1].substringB;
                    score = score2;
                }

                var score3 = SQ[i - 1, j - 1].key + key;
                if (score3 >= score)
                {
                    SQ[i, j].substringA = SQ[i - 1, j - 1].substringA;
                    SQ[i, j].substringB = SQ[i - 1, j - 1].substringB;
                    score = score3;
                }
                SQ[i, j].substringA += a[i];
                SQ[i, j].substringB += b[j];
                SQ[i, j].key = score;
            }
        }
    }

    PrintAlignments(SQ, a.Length, b.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Alignment Score : " + SQ[a.Length - 1, b.Length - 1].key);            
    Console.Read();
}

private static void PrintAlignments(Alignment[,] SQ, int iLength, int jLength)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jLength; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", SQ[i, j].substringA, SQ[i, j].key);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", SQ[i, j].substringB);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dynamic Programming here is populating the matrix SQ by using solutions to sub problems already stored in the matrix SQ

Comment: Also, your solution is probably wrong as the output is wrong. As per the basic definition of the problem, both the strings are supposed to have the same letters as in the original string except for the gaps('-') which have to be inserted optimally in either of the strings. I see that in your output (AGTGATG , -GTTTTA)(score = 8),
(AGTGATTG ,-GTTTTAG)(score = 14), the second string is different in both the solutions which in turn is different from the input string which I believe is "GTTAG"

Comment: @ankitG OK thanks, I understand the Dynamic Programming now. I'll try to see why it's not working.

Comment: Edited the problem statement a bit. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Each state (DP cell) X has 3 predecessor states; let's call them X1, X2, X3.  Let's call the score of a state X s(X), and the cost to get from a state X to some neighbouring state Y c(X, Y).

For any given state X, usually only one of its predecessors will be *optimal*, when measured in terms of its own score plus the cost to get from it to X.  E.g. it might be that s(X1) + c(X1, X) > s(X2) + c(X2, X) and s(X1) + c(X1, X) > s(X3) + c(X3, X): in this case, X1 is uniquely optimal among the 3 predecessors of X, and backtracking need only follow X1.

But it can happen that there are 2 best-equal, or even 3 best-equal predecessors, and in these cases, following any of the 2 or 3 optimal predecessors will (by the correctness of the DP formulation) produce an optimal alignment.  Usually you're only interested in generating a single alignment, so during backtracking you just pick one optimal predecessor arbitrarily, and follow it.  But if you want to generate them all, instead of doing this you need to loop over all predecessor states and recurse to process each one.

Answer (score 0):

Just because problem was actually interesting for me, and I was interested in your approach to the solution I quickly coded a bruteforce solution for some tests. For some trivial problems I discovered we produce different solutions. For example TA and AT. Your score result is 1 (I don't know what is the alignment it bases on), while mine is:

```
TA-
-AT
```

which scores at 3. Maybe I didn't get your problem right, I would be glad if you checked this out.

```
static Dictionary<string, int> dict;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This has been assumed that the strings contain only A,C,G,T and -(?)..caps

        Console.WriteLine("Enter first string : ");
        string realInputA = Console.ReadLine();
        string inputA = "-" + realInputA;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter second string : ");
        string realInputB = Console.ReadLine();
        string inputB = "-" + realInputB;
        int[,] scoreMatrix = new int[inputA.Length, inputB.Length];
        #region Create Dictionary
        dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("AA", 5);
        dict.Add("AC", -1);
        dict.Add("AG", -2);
        dict.Add("AT", -1);
        dict.Add("A-", -3);

        dict.Add("CA", -1);
        dict.Add("CC", 5);
        dict.Add("CG", -3);
        dict.Add("CT", -2);
        dict.Add("C-", -4);

        dict.Add("GA", -2);
        dict.Add("GC", -3);
        dict.Add("GG", 5);
        dict.Add("GT", -2);
        dict.Add("G-", -2);

        dict.Add("TA", -1);
        dict.Add("TC", -2);
        dict.Add("TG", -2);
        dict.Add("TT", 5);
        dict.Add("T-", -1);

        dict.Add("-A", -3);
        dict.Add("-C", -4);
        dict.Add("-G", -2);
        dict.Add("-T", -1);
        dict.Add("--", 0);
        #endregion Create Dictionary

        for (int i = 0; i < inputA.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputB.Length; j++)
            {
                int score = 0, score1 = 0, score2 = 0;
                dict.TryGetValue(inputA[i].ToString() + inputB[j].ToString(), out score);
                dict.TryGetValue("-" + inputB[j].ToString(), out score1);
                dict.TryGetValue(inputA[i].ToString() + "-", out score2);
                if (i == 0)
                    scoreMatrix[i, j] = score1;
                else if (j == 0)
                    scoreMatrix[i, j] = score2;
                else
                    scoreMatrix[i, j] = Math.Max(scoreMatrix[i - 1, j - 1] + score, Math.Max(scoreMatrix[i - 1, j] + score1, scoreMatrix[i, j - 1] + score2));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < inputA.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputB.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(scoreMatrix[i, j] + "   ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Alignment Score : " + scoreMatrix[inputA.Length - 1, inputB.Length - 1]);
        printAllAlignments(realInputA, realInputB);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void printAllAlignments(string inputA, string inputB)
    {
        int minLen = Math.Max(inputA.Length, inputB.Length);
        int maxLen = inputA.Replace("-", "").Length + inputB.Replace("-", "").Length;

        Dictionary<string, int> solutions = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        solutions = prepareStartSequences(inputA, inputB, minLen, solutions);

        addLongerSequences(inputA, minLen, maxLen, solutions);

        var solutionsOrdered = solutions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
        int maxScore = solutionsOrdered.First().Value;

        foreach (var sol in solutionsOrdered.Where(x => x.Value == maxScore))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\tScore: {2}\n\n", sol.Key.Split('|')[0], sol.Key.Split('|')[1], sol.Value);
        }
    }

    private static void addLongerSequences(string inputA, int minLen, int maxLen, Dictionary<string, int> solutions)
    {
        for (int l = minLen + 1; l <= maxLen; l++)
        {
            List<Tuple<string, string>> currCombs = solutions
                .Where(x => x.Key.Length / 2 + 1 == l)
                .Select(x => x.Key.Split('|'))
                .Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x[0], x[1]))
                .ToList();
            foreach (var comb in currCombs)
            {
                for (int idxA = 0; idxA <= inputA.Length; idxA++)
                {
                    for (int idxB = 0; idxB <= inputA.Length; idxB++)
                    {
                        string cA = comb.Item1.Insert(idxA, "-");
                        string cB = comb.Item2.Insert(idxB, "-");
                        int score = getScore(cA, cB);
                        string key = cA + "|" + cB;
                        if (!solutions.ContainsKey(key) && score > int.MinValue)
                        {
                            solutions.Add(key, score);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> prepareStartSequences(string inputA, string inputB, int minLen, Dictionary<string, int> solutions)
    {
        if (inputA.Length == inputB.Length)
            solutions.Add(inputA + "|" + inputB, getScore(inputA, inputB));
        else
        {
            string shorter = inputA.Length > inputB.Length ? inputB : inputA;
            string longer = inputA.Length > inputB.Length ? inputA : inputB;
            int shortLen = shorter.Length;
            List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
            combinations.Add(shorter);

            while (shortLen < minLen)
            {
                List<string> tmpCombinations = new List<string>();
                foreach (string str in combinations)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= shortLen; i++)
                    {
                        tmpCombinations.Add(str.Insert(i, "-"));
                    }
                }
                combinations = tmpCombinations.Distinct().ToList();
                shortLen++;
            }

            foreach (var comb in combinations)
            {
                if (inputA.Length > inputB.Length)
                {
                    solutions.Add(longer + "|" + comb, getScore(longer, comb));
                }
                else
                {
                    solutions.Add(comb + "|" + longer, getScore(comb, longer));
                }
            }
        }

        solutions = solutions.Where(x => x.Value != int.MinValue).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
        return solutions;
    }

    static int getScore(string inputA, string inputB)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputA.Length; i++)
        {
            string key = inputA[i].ToString() + inputB[i].ToString();
            if (key == "--") return int.MinValue;
            result += dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I think you got the question right only. There is some problem in my code. I am gonna work on it. Talking about your solution, its total Brute Force right?? You are computing the score matrix using DP but not using it at all when generating aligned strings. You are trying out all possible combinations I guess. This solution runs in exponential time and is extremely slow and it takes huge memory as well.

Comment: Yes I know it's terribly slow, as I wrote I did it quickly for tests (I left all your code, just changed naming convention), because I was unsure about my understanding of your problem (since many trivial input data in your algorithm produced results different than my head). Now I know my results are correct, so I will work on optimization. Reminds me times I was active on "project euler.net"